# Is there a cleaner way to check for a condition to set a variable then to use a bunch of IF statements?

Tags: codesys

I am looking to possibly shorten my code. It seems super redundent but I am not sure how else I would be checking for a specific condition to set a variable besides a large IF statement?

```
IF MaxContaminationCode := -2 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '000';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := -1 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '00';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 0 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '0';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 1 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '1';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 2 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '2';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 3 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '3';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 4 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '4';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 5 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '5';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 6 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '6';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 7 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '7';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 8 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '8';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 9 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '9';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 10 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '10';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 11 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '11';
    ELSIF MaxContaminationCode := 12 THEN
        ContaminationClass := '12';
    END_IF
```

With this code, I am checking to see if a calculated value (MaxContaminationCode), which is an INT, is a specific value. If it is the specific value set "ContaminationClass" (which is a string), to the respective value.

Comment: You only need 3 cases: -2 and -1, everything else should be a simple int-to-string conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have many different cases, then it is preferable to use the [CASE](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.16.0/en/_cds_st_instruction_case/) statement ('switch' in other languages) as **DrBwts** said. Also, as **Gereon** said, in your example you could decrease the cases you check. So for your example it would look something like this:

```
CASE MaxContaminationCode OF
-2:
  ContaminationClass := '000';
-1:
  ContaminationClass := '00';
0..12: // if you ONLY want 0 to 12, otherwise use ELSE here
  ContaminationClass := INT_TO_STRING(MaxContaminationCode);
END_CASE
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I knew there had to be some way to clean it up, but wasn't sure what that way logically could be.

Comment: Side note: what do you mean by your comment "0..12: // if you ONLY want 0 to 12, otherwise use ELSE here"?

Comment: Clarifying my comment: In `CASE` statements you can specify ranges (example `0..12`, any number between 0 and 12). If you want any number besides -1 and -2 to be converted to STRING, use `ELSE` there (that will include other negative numbers too, like -3 etc.). The example I wrote will do the **exact** same thing you code in your question does, meaning it will return an empty string ("") when `MaxContaminationCode` is a negative number other than -1 and -2, and when it's greater that 12. I don't know if this is the behavior you wanted, thus the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with suggestion above. But to make it even more compact (-2 lines).

```
ContaminationClass := INT_TO_STRING(MaxContaminationCode);
IF MaxContaminationCode = -2 THEN
    ContaminationClass := '000';
ELSIF MaxContaminationCode = -1 THEN
    ContaminationClass := '00';
END_IF
```

Comment: If you are going to go there, then you could shorten my code by having the case and instruction on the same line, like this: `-2: ContaminationClass := '000';`, which is how the CODESYS documentation on CASE does in their example (see the link in my answer). 
FYI, this would make my code 1 line less than yours. I just personally prefer them on separate lines.

Comment: Hey, I just had to give my 2 cents. I can put `IF` and `THEN` also in one line )) Then my code would be only 3 lines. Look I posted my variant not to humiliate yours, just as a part of community. Do not take it personal :))